# Odd Dimension() object in shape of input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am experiencing issues with Tensorflow. I've narrowed the issues down to the format of my input shape of the build() method of a custom Attention layer in tf-keras. I am getting a list of Dimension() objects instead of the actual input-shape. Please help.

Attention Layer

```
    x_attn = []

    for i in range(self.attn_range): #4
        x_attn.append(Attention()(x))

    print("DEBUG:00001")
    x = L.Concatenate(-1)(x_attn)
```

Custom Attention Layer build() method:

```
def build(self,
          input_shape):
    print("DEBUG:00005")
    params_shape = list(input_shape[1:])
    print("DEBUG:00007", params_shape)
    self.query_weights = self.add_weight(
    name='q_weights',
    shape=params_shape,
    initializer=self.q_weights_init
    )
    print("DEBUG:00006")
    self.key_weights = self.add_weight(
    name='key_weights',
    shape=params_shape,
    initializer=self.key_weights_init
    )
    self.val_weights = self.add_weight(
    name='val_weights',
    shape=params_shape,
    initializer=self.value_weights_init
    )
```

Output of param shape debug print function is: 
`DEBUG:00007 [Dimension(10), Dimension(5), Dimension(128)]`

Edit:

Full Error Message as Requested:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 558, in make_tensor_proto
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 558, in <listcomp>
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 65, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got Dimension(10)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Empowerment\.py", line 327, in <module>
    env_actor = ComputerEnv()
  File "Empowerment\.py", line 225, in __init__
    self.dqn = ICDQNAgent(self.state_size + (3,), self.state_size[0], 4)
  File "Empowerment\.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.model, self.autoencoder, self.critic = self.build_model()
  File "Empowerment\.py", line 99, in build_model
    x_attn.append(Attention()(x))
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 591, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1881, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "/home/ai/Desktop/ai_proj/layers.py", line 69, in build
    initializer=self.q_weights_init
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 384, in add_weight
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 663, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    **kwargs_for_getter)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 155, in make_variable
    shape=variable_shape if variable_shape.rank else None)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 259, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 220, in _variable_v1_call
    shape=shape)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 198, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2495, in default_variable_creator
    shape=shape)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 263, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 460, in __init__
    shape=shape)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 604, in _init_from_args
    initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 135, in <lambda>
    init_val = lambda: initializer(shape, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 533, in __call__
    shape, -limit, limit, dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 239, in random_uniform
    shape = _ShapeTensor(shape)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 44, in _ShapeTensor
    return ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtype, name="shape")
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1087, in convert_to_tensor
    return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1145, in convert_to_tensor_v2
    as_ref=False)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1224, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 305, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 246, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 284, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 562, in make_tensor_proto
    "supported type." % (type(values), values))
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [Dimension(10), Dimension(5), Dimension(128)]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Comment: You should describe the full problem, not what you think the problem is, this would be an XY problem

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, fair point. I have added the full traceback and error details to hopefully add more details and information. Please feel free to ask for more information to help out in solving my issue.